# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 articles for ViewModel and partial view, Edit Templates, Validations and Custom Binders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, viewmodel

I am very confused and scratching my head. I am trying to implement a complex page with many partial Views and Nested ViewModels, but somehow i am not able complete because of my limited understanding of technology. Please help me in understanding the below topics from asp.NET MVC 2 by providing good article/tutorials

```
1. Partial Views 
2. Nested ViewModel 
3. Custom ViewModel Binders.
```

I would really appreciate your help as right now i am trying to implement them without proper understanding and getting confused
Note: I can't buy the book as its not available at my remote place.

Note: Still waiting for the reponse
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a good understanding of any technology you really should buy a book. A book give you a much better understanding of the technology than reading blog posts. Blog posts tend to highlight a particular feature or problem without giving you the big picture.

However, since you asked for it, if you need authoritive info on MVC read the blogs of the (ex-)Microsoft guys involved in building it, for example :

- [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/aspnet_mvc/)
- [Phil Haacked](http://haacked.com/tags/aspnetmvc/default.aspx)
- [Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/tags/ASP.NET+MVC/default.aspx)
- [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx)

There's also a bunch of info op on [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

I personally recommend the following books :

- [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 (Wrox)](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-3.productCd-1118076583.html), this book will educate you on all the topics you mentioned.
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 in action (Manning)](http://www.manning.com/palermo3/), there's a [MVC2](http://www.manning.com/palermo2/) edition as well.

Both books are available as downloads from the publisher at reasonable rates, so you can start reading right away.

Finally I would recommend an upgrade to MVC3 if possible, it'll make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks Marnix for your valuable response :)